# Is calling a bunch of HTML in a JS function bad practice?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

I am doing a few things to my text input via `"oninput=myFunction()"`

**When I start typing I wanted to do a few things:**

I have the function `removing a few elements` and `adding a textNode already`, however, I need it to add `35-40 lines of HTML` as well.

**Would this be bad to do?**

I'm not exactly sure how I should set it up to call this HTML through the function yet.

**What's the best/cleanest way to go about doing this?**

Should I just keep the HTML wrapped with a `hidden  display:none class`, and have the function add a visible class?

I feel like that wouldn't be the best method, so that's why I'm here asking!

Any advice is appreciated. I'm typing on my phone so sorry if I wasn't very clear.

Comment: I would favour a solution where the HTML fragment is already in the DOM. But which alternative are you comparing with? Assigning a JavaScript string literal to an `innerHTML` property? It would be helpful if you would post the two (or more) alternatives of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way in my opinion is have a script that will add your event handler after the element is ready (after page load). This function should take care of creating and removing any element that are part of the script on the fly.

Doing this will make sure your HTML is clean and that the JavaScript will do what it is responsible for. There are good ways to create HTML with JavaScript by using methods such as `document.createElement` and `document.createTextNode`. When your elements are created, you can append them in the right positions.

To help get the best rendering on all browsers, it is usually a good practice to make your elements `display: none` before everything is ready to display.

Comment: @Kaiido That's why usually you would use a class with `display: none`. You can easily animate it by removing the class with CSS or Javascript.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm really not sure about what this means... this property can be removed with JavaScript and then you can do whatever you need with the HTML element? I'm using `display: none` on all my animations and its work like a charm using JavaScript. removeChild can also work but some older browsers are known to have issues with non appended elements.

Comment: @Kaiido I meant transition from not visible to visible... once it's visible you can do whatever you want with the element.

Comment: @Kaiido Well depending on the heaviness of the HTML, some rendering engine can be clunky on old and/or mobile browsers. I personally try to display dynamic objects only when they are ready but maybe its paranoia. I'm not convinced about the question either but maybe my answer will help!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I have done now. It works great, just wanted to make sure it wasn't too sloppy.